# Generate hash for nested DTO objects in Java by excluding a few fields in order to persist in DB

Tags: java, hash

Java library:

I plan to store hash for a Nested DTO object where I need to include fields from subclass/nested class. Is there any library that I can use which would return me a hash & where I can exclude fields by just adding annotations over the fields?

I plan to not use this in comparison but for some purpose, I need to persist in DB.

For e.g. if I have a

```java
Class Car {
    @ExcludeField
    int id

    int modelYear

    String color

    TyreClass tyre;
}
```

```java
Class TyreClass {
   
   @ExcludeField
   int id;

   @ExcludeField
   int version;

   float radius

   String colour

   double width
}
```

In this case, if I can have any library which would allow me to get hash for Car (including for tyreClass)? I need java solutions/library for this

Expecting to return an integer or a string has a value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great library called Lombok that provides functionality of marking only specific fields to be included (or excluded) into hashcode.

Marking needed classes with EqualsAndHashCode annotation and adding EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude annotation to fields that are expected to be excluded from hashcode would do the job.

With it your class could look like:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Car {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    int id

    int modelYear

    String color

    TyreClass tyre;
}
```

and

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
Class TyreClass {
   
   @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
   int id;

   @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
   int version;

   float radius

   String colour

   double width
}
```

Comment: I have couple of queries on this. 1. Since this will impact the existing hashtable/map/comparisons, so I was looking for some library which will not change the behaviour of internal apis but provide hash? 2. Since I want to generate the hashcode via invoking the parent class only, so will I get the hash that combines the sub-classes?

Comment: I am looking for something like - Apache commons HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode()...but the thing is works up the hierarchy & not the down as we have in merkels algo..